My application on avd emulator when i run the code the phone emulator just flashes like its in a infinity loop
what could be the problem ? i dont see nothing wrong in my code but this application is giving me black ad white flashes like its restarting every second
log cat says : ~A resource failed to call release.
Main.activity.java
package com.example.xyzenterprises;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Objects;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        loadLocale();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setTitle(R.string.app_name);

        findViewById(R.id.welcomeLabel);
        Button nextButton = findViewById(R.id.nextButton);

        nextButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.language_english) {
            setLocale("en");
            return true;
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.language_french) {
            setLocale("fr");
            return true;
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.language_spanish) {
            setLocale("es");
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void setLocale(String lang) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("My_Lang", lang);
        editor.apply();
        recreate();
    }

    public void loadLocale() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String language = prefs.getString("My_Lang", "en");
        setLocale(language);
    }
}


strings.xml
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">XYZ Enterprises</string>
    <string name="welcome_label">Welcome to XYZ Enterprises</string>
    <string name="next_button">Next</string>
    <string name="step_closer_label">You\'re one step closer!</string>
    <string name="language">Language</string>
    <string name="english">English</string>
    <string name="french">French</string>
    <string name="spanish">Spanish</string>
</resources>


android.manifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.XYZEnterprises"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

see image
enter image description here
i tried checking for any syntax error code seems correct...
i expect the code to work and execute on the awd emulator
